# Code returns "'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" when trying to implement a simple function in Pandas

Tags: excel, pandas, string, integer

I have an excel sheet of medical data formatted as numbers.

```
e = pd.read_excel('AIPFR_otherDx_data.xlsx')
```

I am reading the file into a DF using pandas

I am then trying to implement a simple function

```
def exposure(row):
    if str(row['Exposure_hydralazine']) == str(1):
       return "Yes"
    else:
       return "No"
```

And trying to create a new column "any_exposure" based on this functions evaluation

```
e['any_exposure'] = p.apply(exposure, axis=1)
```

I keep running into this error

```
'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

for this line:

```
if str(row['Exposure_hydralazine']) == str(1):
```

This seems like a really simple thing but I can't find the solution. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `e['any_exposure'] = np.where(e['Exposure_hydralazine']).astype(str) == '1'), 'Yes', 'No')`? or just use `replace`

Comment: Thanks - there is a stray parenthesis but this is good. Please answer